# Inner Outer class relationship

Tags: java, uml, relationship, inner-classes, class-diagram

I encountered a similar scenario from a project which I'm currently working on. I tried simulating the same with some general context. Follow the code below:

```
interface Receptor
{
    public void recept();  
}

class Human
{
    private void bloodCirculate(String receptor)
    {
        System.out.println("Blood flows in " + receptor);
    }

    public class Eye implements Receptor
    {    
        @Override
        public void recept()
        {
            bloodCirculate("eye");
            System.out.println("Look");      
        }
    }

    private class Ear implements Receptor
    {    
        @Override
        public void recept()
        {
            bloodCirculate("ear");
            System.out.println("Listen");      
        }
    }

    private void recept(Receptor receptor)
    {
        receptor.recept();    
    }

    public void look()
    {
        recept(new Eye());
    }

    public void listen()
    {
        recept(new Ear());
    }
}
```

I was trying of identifying the relationship between the two classes. It's not inheritance because, outer class's private methods are accessible within the inner class. It slightly looks Association relation since the inner class's object is kept within the outer class.

Comment: At least for Ear it's clearly Composition since Human has full control over its lifecycle.

Comment: Yes, in UML terms, both the Human-Eye and the Human-Ear relationships are associations of aggregation kind = Composite.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Since `Eye` is public with a public constructor, another class may get its own instance of it. That would violate composition.

Comment: Nice to see the eyes being public. Can you lend me an eye? In German it's common to "lend me your ear" (can you please listen to me). So that's probably an implementation from a different culture ;-)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik. No. If the multiplicity at the Human side is "0..1", then there may exist Eye-instances not contained in any Human instance.

Comment: Seems you restated what I said, @www.admiraalit.nl

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, I mean: this doesn't violate composition. You can have a composition relationship with a "0..1" multiplicity at the composite side. In that case, ONLY if a particular Eye-instance has a link with a particular Human-instance, then these INSTANCES form a composition. There may be Eye-instances without a Human-instance.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Since Eye is an inner class, it always has an enclosing Human instance. Yes that instance has no control over its lifecycle.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, I guess it's too long ago I developed some Java code. Yes, my previous comment was wrong, thanks for pointing out. But what do you mean by "no control over its lifecycle"? Suppose the enclosing Human instance is destructed, I guess all its Eye-instances are destructed as well, aren't they? I would consider this sufficient to call it composition. UML 2.5 spec, page 110: "The precise lifecycle semantics of composite aggregation is intentionally not specified."

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl The Human instance is actually at the mercy of the Eye instance because it's reachable through it. Sometimes this implicit fact even causes memory leaks when you publish the inner instance to a framework that retains it.

Comment: Interesting, thanks!

Comment: Well, we're discussing here two things. One is actual or theoretical code and a model most accurately representing it (and my answer is referring to that). From that perspective the object of type Human.Eye does not need to be a part of object typed Human. On the other hand you may have an actual "life" situation in which you actually have that limitation, just not shown here. The model would be a bit different then (to be more specific you'd have additional associations representing that, and then they'd be composite aggregations). Question directly said - it's not about being an aggregation.

Answer (score 3):

According to 11.4.3.1 of UML specification

> A Class acts as the namespace for various kinds of Classifiers defined within its scope, including Classes. Nested Classifiers are members of the namespace of the containing Class. Classifier nesting is used for reasons of information hiding.

So in your case Eye and Ear are nested in Human. Unfortunately specification does not provide a nesting operator for classes. You can present them in additional compartment (UML leaves a lot of flexibility in what can you present in compartments other than 4 mandatory) like suggested for nested Classes for a Component (see 11.6.5, especially Figure 11.45). You could eventually also consider a notation that is specific for Packages, that is a line with a plus in a circle at the nesting Package (in your case on Human side). This is presented in 12.2.5, especially Figure 12.5. Note however that formally this second notation is suitable only to Packages, not Classes.

Comment: Excellent answer. I think the word "eventually" is misused here. Did you mean "alternatively"?

Comment: No, I meant "eventually" as this notation is formally defined for packages only and the question is about classes. Whenever the specification is not clear enough in allowing something I try to use only slight encourages. "Alternatively" would be a bit to strong in current stage of specification, at least in my opinion. Anyway - thanks for your credit.

Comment: Okay, English is not my native language, but I read "eventually" as "after a long time"/"when you have come at the end", not as "possibly, if you really need to".

Comment: Well me neither and I'm not even quite sure if this use was correct, however I can find nothing better than that. The meaning I wanted to achieve was "it's a possible but discouraged (unsupported) alternative".